# xacro formatting xacro file property with given param

Tags: ros-noetic, xacro

thisis my example xacro file and I need to change robot_namespace property's value

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<robot name="turtlebot3_waffle_pi_sim" xmlns:xacro="http://ros.org/wiki/xacro">

<xacro:property name="robot_namespace" value="robot1"/> 
  <plugin name="turtlebot3_waffle_pi_controller" filename="libgazebo_ros_diff_drive.so">
      <odometryTopic>${robot_namespace}/odom</odometryTopic>
  <odometryFrame>${robot_namespace}/odom</odometryFrame>

    </plugin>

</robot>
```

I am trying to format this file with **xacro pathOfXacroFile robot_namespace:=robot2**
but in the output it shows always the default value not the formatted one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to override the `robot_namespace` in the xacro file. For your scenario, you need to set the xacro **property** using a xacro argument (**arg**).

- **Modify your xacro file:** Adding an arg means we enable the file to accept command line arguments. Let's make an arg for the `robot_namespace`.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<robot name="turtlebot3_waffle_pi_sim" xmlns:xacro="http://ros.org/wiki/xacro">

  <!-- New arg to add with the same default -->
  <xacro:arg name="robot_namespace" default="robot1"/>
  <xacro:property name="robot_namespace" value="$(arg robot_namespace)"/> 
  
  <plugin name="turtlebot3_waffle_pi_controller" filename="libgazebo_ros_diff_drive.so">
      <odometryTopic>${robot_namespace}/odom</odometryTopic>
  <odometryFrame>${robot_namespace}/odom</odometryFrame>
  </plugin>
</robot>
```

- **Test with the same command in the question:**

```
xacro pathOfXacroFile robot_namespace:=robot2
```

This will print the xacro file content with the required change. Hope this helps!